# Trying to send ArrayList info to other fragment but does not work

Tags: android, listview, android-fragments, nullpointerexception

I am trying to send an `ArrayList` data (from a `Fragment`) to another `Fragment` to create a adapter there for the `ListView`(called lv) in that Fragment.

Error:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.util.ArrayList android.os.Bundle.getStringArrayList(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference at rang.afterflight.fragments.DemandFragment.onCreateView(DemandFragment.java:38)
```

FinishPostFragment:

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.add_post_finish:
            // User chose the "Favorite" action, mark the current item
            // as a favorite...
            FragmentManager fm = getActivity().getFragmentManager();
            final Fragment fragment = new DemandFragment();

            // put strings to listview in DemandFragment
            ParseObject post = new ParseObject("Posts");

            post.put("airport", airport_finish.getText().toString());
            post.put("date", date_finish.getText().toString());
            post.put("time", time_finish.getText().toString());
            post.put("persons", persons_finish.getText().toString());
            post.put("address", address_finish.getText().toString());
            post.put("flightnr", flightnr_finish.getText().toString());

            post.saveInBackground(new SaveCallback() {
                @Override
                public void done(ParseException e) {
                    airport_finish.setText("");
                    date_finish.setText("");
                    time_finish.setText("");
                    persons_finish.setText("");
                    address_finish.setText("");
                    flightnr_finish.setText("");

                    ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = ParseQuery.getQuery("Posts");
                    query.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseObject>() {
                        public void done(List<ParseObject> scoreList, ParseException e) {
                            if (e == null) {
                                ArrayList arrayPost = new ArrayList<String>();

                                for (ParseObject j : scoreList) {

                                    arrayPost.add(j.getString("airport"));
                                    arrayPost.add(j.getString("date"));
                                    arrayPost.add(j.getString("time"));
                                    arrayPost.add(j.getString("persons"));
                                    arrayPost.add(j.getString("address"));
                                    arrayPost.add(j.getString("flightnr"));
                                }

                                Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
                                bundle.putStringArrayList("listPost", arrayPost);
                                fragment.setArguments(bundle);

                            } else {
                                // error
                            }
                        }
                    });
                }
            });

                    fm.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.content_main, new DemandFragment()).commit();
            return true;
```

DemandFragment:

```
public class DemandFragment extends Fragment {

ListView lv;

ArrayList yourList;
ArrayAdapter adapter;

@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_demand, container, false);

    if(rootView != null){
        lv = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.listDemand);

        ArrayList<String> arraypost = getArguments().getStringArrayList("listPost");
        Log.d("arraylist", "arraypost");

        ArrayAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter(getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, arraypost);

        lv.setAdapter(adapter);

        lv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                // clicked on item show post

            }
        });
    }

    return rootView;
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setHasOptionsMenu(true);

}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

This method `fragment.setArguments(bundle)` is called in a background thread. So when you retrieve ArrayList in `onCreateView()` method, the arguments may not be set yet.

And in this code:

```
 fm.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.content_main, new DemandFragment()).commit();
```

You created new DemandFragment instead of using `fragment` variable.

Comment: You are telling me what is wrong... but what is the solution for my code?

Comment: @Rang92 use fm.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.content_main, fragment).commit();  instead of the line in Rey's answer.

Answer (score 1):

You are creating a new DemandFragment and adding it to the fragment manager.  You then are setting arguments on a final fragment that is not added to the fragment manager.  So the fragment in the manager has no arguments.

```
 fm.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.content_main, new DemandFragment()).commit();
```

You probably want to add the fragment that you are actually setting arguments on to the fragment manager.

```
 fm.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.content_main, fragment).commit();
```

You also need to make sure that you are reading the arguments after they have been set...

It would probably be easiest to do all this in the callback.  i.e. Get the fragment manager, create a new fragment, set the arguments, then add it to the fragment manager.  You can then be assured that you can retrieve the arguments in the fragment's onCreate() method.

Comment: Dont understand the last part... which callback?

Comment: In the done method of the FindCallback, where you create the bundle and call setArguments - you should do everything there.  Create the fragment, setArguments, and do the fragment manager replace transaction.

Comment: Thanks it works, the only this is now that every string is in seperate items.....

Answer (score 0):

Try to retrieve your `ArrayList` in [onActivityCreated()](http://developer.android.com/intl/zh-tw/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#onActivityCreated(android.os.Bundle)) method of your fragment and it should work.

**update**:

As *Rey* said, use:

```
fm.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.content_main, fragment).commit();
```

instead of:

```
fm.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.content_main, new DemandFragment()).commit();
```

Comment: This did not work:

@Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        ArrayList<String> arraypost = getArguments().getStringArrayList("listPost");
        Log.d("arraylist", "arraypost");

        ArrayAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter(getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, arraypost);

        lv.setAdapter(adapter);
    }